# How can I make this custom JButton work?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I've looked through so many threads- and none have helped me.
Here is my code:

```
package myProjects;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class LukeButton extends JButton{
public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Luke");
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    LukeButton lb = new LukeButton("Text");
    lb.addActionListener(e->{
        System.out.println("Clicked");
    });

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
public LukeButton(String text){

}
public void paint(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

    Shape rec = new Rectangle2D.Float(10, 10, 60, 80);

    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
    g2.draw(rec);
    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2.fill(rec);
    }
}
```

And the rectangle that is supposed to be there, isn't. I don't know if this is not allowed when extending JButton, but if it's not, I don't know how to fix it. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A main problem: You don't add your LukeButton instance to the GUI. Solution: add it via a container's `add(lb)` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LukeButton lb = new LukeButton("Text");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(lb);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(panel);
```

Other problems:

- You should override the paintComponent method not the paint method
- Call the super's paintComponent method in the override
- Override the getPreferredSize of your component.
- Don't ignore the String being passed into your constructor's parameter. You'll probably want to pass it into the super's constructor.
- You're likely far better off not using inheritance to do whatever it is you're trying to do, that is, to not extend JButton. If you can give us more detail of your overall problem, we can help.

Comment: Thanks, it works now, I can't believe that went past me! And for the parameter in the constructor, I was gonna use that for the text on the button, but just hadn't done it yet :) Thanks again.

Comment: I read your edit, and my goal is to have a button (The one I have now is just fine) that I can use in replace of The boring JButton. But I really don't know how to tackle the problem.